# Blockly domToWorkspace reset node IDs

Tags: javascript, blockly

I'm working on an code editor using blockly, and my page currently has tabs for switching between Block View and Code View, kinda like some WYSIWYG editors. Now, Blockly already has plenty of stuff for going from blocks to code, and I've gotten 99% of the parts done so that I can go from code to blocks (it involves building up a bunch of block xml). My call to go from code view to block view looks like this:

```
var xml = Blockly.Xml.textToDom(self.xmlGenerated());
Blockly.mainWorkspace.clear();
Blockly.Xml.domToWorkspace(Blockly.mainWorkspace, xml);
```

The problem is, no matter what id attributes I set in my xml nodes, blockly overrides them when I try to read the block xml later. It seems they constantly increment, even though I'm clearing the workspace. This causes a problem for my auto-save feature since that means each time I go from code to blocks my xml is changing, and therefore my code is changing (the generated code is a graph structure that also uses the id fields to identity each node in the graph).

So, my question is, does anyone know how to prevent Blockly from overriding the node id I send, or is there a way to "reset" the node ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a very similar question in the Blockly Google group and Neil added a new `data` XML tag for storing persistent data. Maybe you can put your ID there? From reading the code seems like the `id` attribute was meant for internal use so it may be unreliable to reuse it.

Comment: That sounds like it would work. Is it a new element or a new attribute? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: It's a new element: `<data>`...`</data>`. It's only documented in the mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/blockly/CbSDz849fiE), but I'm not sure there's good documentation for any of the Blockly XML

Comment: That's a fair point. Based on his description I don't know how complex objects would work in there, but for my id field it would be perfect. Thanks!